# In IE9 and IE10 rotated container doesn't clip its rotated nested elements as it is supposed to

Tags: css, rotation, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/aFEZ8/3/

### HTML

```
<span id="square"></span>
<div id="wrap">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#wrap{
position:absolute;
left:100px;
top:100px;
border:solid 1px #000;
width:100px;
height:100px;
-webkit-transform:rotate(33deg);
overflow:hidden;
transform:rotate(33deg);
}
#wrap div{
-webkit-transform:rotate(-33deg);
-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
transform:rotate(-33deg);
transform-origin:0 0;
height:100%;
width:200%;
border:solid 1px #f00;
cursor:pointer;
position:absolute;
}
#square{
position:absolute;
left:200px;
top:100px;
width:4px;
height:4px;
background:#aaa;
}
```

If you try to hover the gray square, you'll see pointer in IE 9 and 10, which is wrong.

What should I do to make things right?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of frustration I found a solution: you just have to add extra wrapper, which is not rotated - it correctly clips its inner elements: http://jsfiddle.net/aFEZ8/4/

```
If someone thinks it's a good idea to add code here, please feel free to do it.
I think it's superfluous in this case.
```

With multiple nested rotated containers and some effort spent on calculating margins and angles it becomes possible to make polygonal clips of arbitrary html, where cursor hovering works correctly, which IMO is a great alternative to not-so-good-supported clipping html with svg.

More complicated example: http://jsfiddle.net/aFEZ8/5/
Crispy edges in Chrome(ver. 29, Win 7)...oh, well. Other modern browsers(at least desktop, including "last" Safari for Windows) don't have this issue.